# How to change a column in the Database to have random values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am using Postgresql Version:  9.6.24

I want to change all "names" (Strings) in the column "name" inside the Table "employee" to be random values.

This is the function that I am trying to run:

```
UPDATE employee SET name = (
    SELECT string_agg(
        (SELECT substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'::text from floor(random() * 26) + 1 for 1) 
         FROM generate_series(1, 6)), ' '
    )
    FROM generate_series(1, 2)
)
WHERE userid = 120;
```

However this gives me this error:

```
Error SQL (7): ERROR: function pg_catalog.substring(text, double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 3: (SELECT substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'::text...
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

When I try to use this:

```
UPDATE employee SET name = (
    SELECT string_agg(
        (SELECT substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', floor(random() * 26) + 1, 1) 
         FROM generate_series(1, 6)), ' '
    )
    FROM generate_series(1, 2)
)
WHERE userid = 120;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in SQL(7): ERROR: function substr(unknown, double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 3: (SELECT substr('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', floor(r...
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Edit: I ended up with this query.

```
UPDATE employee SET name = (
    SELECT string_agg(
        substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' from floor(random() * 26)::integer + 1 for 1), ''
    )
    FROM generate_series(1, 12)
)
WHERE userid = 120;
```

It "works" because I get this random "name" updated: "pqxhudurrhrw".

What I want is to have the string to look like a name tho, so like this: "pqxhud urrhrw". Any tipps on this?

Comment: Like the error says - you can't use a floating-point result (from `floor`) as an index for the substring. Cast it to an integer.

Comment: @RichardHuxton hey ty Richard, I updated my Question maybe you can take a look.

Comment: FYI, Postgres 9.6 is ~1.25 years past EOL per [Versioning](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I have the query the way I want it.

```
UPDATE employee SET name = (
    SELECT string_agg(
        CASE 
            WHEN row_number % 6 = 0 THEN ' '
            ELSE substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' from floor(random() * 26)::integer + 1 for 1)
        END, ''
    )
    FROM generate_series(1, 12)
    WITH ORDINALITY as t(x, row_number)
)
WHERE userid = 120;
```

This gives me a Random Name that is 12 Char long with a split after 6 Chars. So the resulting String looks like this:

```
"rujvl pafyr"
```

Comment: IF someone knows how I could run that query on the whole table would be great! The Problem is that it generates the same name for every entry instead of a new random one.